# Can't play video with AVKit

Tags: ios, swift, avkit

I am trying to make a video player but somehow I can't see the video playing, although I can hear its sound. I've tried using AVPlayerViewController like so:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class VideoPlayerViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var videoPlayer: AVPlayer?
    
    private let videoUrls = [
        "https://wolverine.raywenderlich.com/content/ios/tutorials/video_streaming/foxVillage.mp4",
        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupVideoPlayer()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        presentVideoPlayerViewController()
    }
    
    private func setupVideoPlayer() {
        guard let url = URL(string: videoUrls.randomElement()!) else { return }
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
    }

    private func presentVideoPlayerViewController() {
        guard let player = videoPlayer else { return }
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player

        present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
          player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

And using AVPlayerLayer like so:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class VideoPlayerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoPlayerView: UIView!
    
    private var videoPlayer: AVPlayer?
    private var videoPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
    
    private let videoUrls = [
        "https://wolverine.raywenderlich.com/content/ios/tutorials/video_streaming/foxVillage.mp4",
        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupVideoPlayer()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        setupVideoPlayerView()
        videoPlayer?.play()
     }
    
    private func setupVideoPlayer() {
        guard let url = URL(string: videoUrls.randomElement()!) else { return }
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
    }

    private func setupVideoPlayerView() {
        guard let playerLayer = getPlayerLayer(from: videoPlayer) else {
            return
        }
        
        videoPlayerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        
        videoPlayerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        videoPlayerLayer = playerLayer
    }

    private func getPlayerLayer(from player: AVPlayer?) -> AVPlayerLayer? {
        guard let player = player else {
            return nil
        }

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        playerLayer.frame = videoPlayerView.bounds
        return playerLayer
    }
}
```

Both worked on an iOS 14 simulator. But I've got these errors in an iOS 11.4 simulator:

```
2021-08-04 20:56:42.723171+0700 Video player[31906:850466] Task <5845D991-1144-40FE-AD2A-1AA98E73F9D7>.<2> finished with error - code: -999
2021-08-04 20:56:44.071786+0700 Video player[31906:850466] Task <3B49CB9C-97ED-46AC-BC9C-11B126625311>.<3> finished with error - code: -999
2021-08-04 20:56:44.382677+0700 Video player[31906:850653] Task <8DEA7E92-4E54-4105-9A5A-801320090CB6>.<1> finished with error - code: -999
2021-08-04 20:56:47.080039+0700 Video player[31906:850881] [AudioHAL_Client] HALB_IOBufferManager.cpp:226:GetIOBuffer:  HALB_IOBufferManager::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
2021-08-04 20:56:47.082504+0700 Video player[31906:850881] [AudioHAL_Client] HALB_IOBufferManager.cpp:226:GetIOBuffer:  HALB_IOBufferManager::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
2021-08-04 20:56:47.313237+0700 Video player[31906:850881] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (1): output stream 0: null buffer
2021-08-04 20:56:47.315029+0700 Video player[31906:850881] [aqme] 1433: EXCEPTION thrown (-50): -
2021-08-04 20:57:01.906151+0700 Video player[31906:850653] [aqme] 177: timed out after 15.000s (0 1); suspension count=0 (IOSuspensions: )
2021-08-04 20:57:01.975129+0700 Video player[31906:850653] 239: CA_UISoundClientBase::StartPlaying: AddRunningClient failed (status = -66681).
2021-08-04 20:57:02.911820+0700 Video player[31906:851213] [AudioHAL_Client] HALB_IOBufferManager.cpp:226:GetIOBuffer:  HALB_IOBufferManager::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
2021-08-04 20:57:02.916048+0700 Video player[31906:851213] [AudioHAL_Client] HALB_IOBufferManager.cpp:226:GetIOBuffer:  HALB_IOBufferManager::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
2021-08-04 20:57:02.960249+0700 Video player[31906:851213] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (1): output stream 0: null buffer
2021-08-04 20:57:02.970924+0700 Video player[31906:851213] [aqme] 1433: EXCEPTION thrown (-50): -
2021-08-04 20:57:17.637706+0700 Video player[31906:850656] Task <53514ED1-3A24-4BA2-A676-17A7B8FC7165>.<3> finished with error - code: -999
2021-08-04 20:57:17.672290+0700 Video player[31906:851196] [aqme] 177: timed out after 15.000s (1 2); suspension count=0 (IOSuspensions: )
2021-08-04 20:57:28.633691+0700 Video player[31906:851601] Task <CC6ED234-5DCF-49DD-8D9F-4D600E943760>.<4> finished with error - code: -999
2021-08-04 20:57:28.747661+0700 Video player[31906:851627] [AudioHAL_Client] HALB_IOBufferManager.cpp:226:GetIOBuffer:  HALB_IOBufferManager::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
2021-08-04 20:57:28.750375+0700 Video player[31906:851627] [AudioHAL_Client] HALB_IOBufferManager.cpp:226:GetIOBuffer:  HALB_IOBufferManager::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
2021-08-04 20:57:28.921880+0700 Video player[31906:851627] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (1): output stream 0: null buffer
2021-08-04 20:57:28.932579+0700 Video player[31906:851627] [aqme] 1433: EXCEPTION thrown (-50): -
2021-08-04 20:57:28.992942+0700 Video player[31906:851601] Task <DF0FCD41-0E01-46EC-85F8-257C798C1284>.<5> finished with error - code: -999
2021-08-04 20:57:43.128655+0700 Video player[31906:851616] [aqme] 177: timed out after 15.000s (2 3); suspension count=0 (IOSuspensions: )
```

BTW, I'm using Swift 5 with XCode 12.5.1. My OS is Big Sur 11.4. Can anybody help me fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Try it by creating an `AVPlayerItem` object.

Comment: @ElTomato Good idea. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: @ElTomato the problem is still happening. So that doesn't solve it, I'm afraid.